# How to organize storyboard with multiple sections in iOS?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode8

I am busy to learn building applications for iOS and started creating one by myself. I am currently running against the following and am curious about the process of other iOS developers out here.

Populair apps like Twitter has multiple sections within a view controller. What is the best method to organize a layout on one Storyboard with multiple sections like a header section with labels, a tableview and a mapview?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What is the best way to..." type questions are not a good fit for SO. That leads to opinion-based answers, and possible arguments.

Better to ask "What are some options to..." type questions.

If you are looking to create a modular design where you divide your screen into discrete tiles, you can look at using container views and embed segues. With that design you can make a view controller responsible for a section of the screen. Then you can embed one of those view controllers in another view controller wherever you want it.

I won't say it is "the best" way, but it is an approach that can be useful.